# Javascript return value from setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I want do something like that:

```
var x = function(){
  if (controlVar === 0) {
    setTimeout(x, 300);
  }
  else {
    return value;
};
```

Is there a method in js for call a function like in synchronous code `(var z = x())` and return a value only when my controlVar turn in 1?

This should not block, because when I use setTimeout the main loop shoul be able to take the control, but if block doesn't matter for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, this must not block, because if block my controlVar can't turn in 1.

Comment: Please try to describe what you're trying to achieve and not just the problem.

Comment: For clarify I want call a recursive function that return only when a variable that act like a semaphore turn green. And I want call this function like that 'var x = f(z)'

Comment: No. If you don't want to block (and you don't want to), you can't `return` the value from asynchronous callback.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at AJAX and WebWorkers as potential solutions for this, but it's not really possible with basic JavaScript given that it runs to completion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method in js for call a function like in synchronous code (`var z = x()`) and return a value only when my controlVar turn in 1?

No. Assignment is synchronous. It can't wait for an asynchronous function. To be more precise, `x` immediately returns, it doesn't wait for the timeout.

`setTimeout` simply adds a new job to the job queue. Only after the *current* job is finished, the next job will be processed.

> I want call a recursive function that return only when a variable that act like a semaphore turn green.

That doesn't work in JavaScript because it has the concept of ["run to completion"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion):

> Each message is processed completely before any other message is processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it can be stopped at any point to run some other code in another thread.

Going back to your example, we start with evaluating the script and calling `x`. This is the current status the job queue:

```
Job Queue--------------------------------------------------+
| +---------------------+                                  |
| |What: evaluate script|                                  |
| |                     |                                  |
| |                     |                                  |
| +---------------------+                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

When the line `setTimeout(x, 300);` is executed, a new entry is added to the job queue:

```
Job Queue--------------------------------------------------+
| +---------------------+    +-----------------+           |
| |What: evaluate script|    |What: execute x  |           |
| |                     |    |When: 300ms      |           |
| |                     |    |                 |           |
| +---------------------+    +-----------------+           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

In order for the the next entry to be processed, the *current job* must be completed first. That means, since we are currently calling `x`, `x` must terminate. Only after `x` returned, the event loop can move on to the next job and call `x` again.

Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer why `x` cannot wait for the timeout.

---

For alternative solutions see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) .

Comment: thanks this is very clear